# Do I have to claim and re-check in my baggage in international transit when travelling with the same air line?

Tags: transit, luggage, connecting-flights

I'll be traveling to Berlin, Germany from Colombo, Sri Lanka via Turkish Airways.

The itinerary would be: Colombo  <--> Istanbul- || Istanbul- <--> Berlin

The flights are all on one ticket. Would I be required to claim and re-check my baggage at Istanbul or can I check it in all the way from Colombo to Berlin without re-checking in the baggage again?

Answer (score 2):

You do not need to collect your bags again.

As you are flying on *one ticket*; the agent will check your bags all the way to your final destination - you will not need to collect your bags and check-in again in Istanbul.

You will also be given boarding passes for both legs of your journey at your check-in in Colombo.

If you purchased two separate tickets (even if they were both on Turkish Airlines):

Colombo - Istanbul
Istanbul - Berlin

Then you will have to ensure:

1. You have a valid visa for Turkey
2. You will have to enter into Turkey, collect your luggage.
3. You will have to check-in again in Turkey for your second leg.

Unless you booked the tickets manually - the above does not apply to you. If you booked your flight through a travel agent or through the turkish airlines website, you are on one ticket where your bags will be checked in to your final destination.

For more information, you can browse the excellent [transit information page](http://www.turkishairlines.com/en-int/travel-information/baggage/transit-transfer-passenger-procedures) on the Turkish Airlines website.

Comment: Usually, it's possible to check in to two tickets and register the baggage to the final destination if they start within 24 hours. But this doesn't work for everyone...